# CSS: setting font's height relatively to the parent's height

Tags: css, fonts, height, size, parent

Is there any CSS standard for setting font's height relatively to the parent's height? I mean parent's height, not it's text size. 
I can't find that on the internet, so I think it does not exist. Maybe one of you works for w3c and tell them about it?

Comment: Consider using [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) or CSS viewport units...

Comment: Viewport units are not supported in default browser on Android < 4.4. So I have to use JS? :/

Comment: I think JS is your only hope, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a CSS standard that can set the `font-size` as a relative value of it's parents' `height`.

According to the [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-size):

> A **relative-size** keyword is interpreted relative to the table of font sizes and the font size of the parent element.

What you are trying to do simply is not possible in CSS today. You will need to get the height of the parent (with or without borders, margins, and paddings) then apply the style after it has been rendered through other means, like JavaScript.

If you want to participate in the W3C discussion, you can do so here: https://www.w3.org/participate/ If your suggestion has enough value it may be considered to be added in the future, but I wouldn't count on that happening very quickly.